# Wordpress front-page.php is active, how to add home.php to navigation?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on some wordpress theme where I used custom front-page.php to be my homepage, home.php is page where I have written posts loop. But the problem is how to include that home.php to my navigation? I have created custom navigation menu, and added some items in it, but I don't know how to add home.php?!

any help, please? :S

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're asking. Do you want to get the URL for the posts page that uses home.php to add to a custom coded nav? Or do you mean you want to add it to a WordPress menu?

Comment: hey, I want to add it to a wordpress menu :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to pages and create two pages. I'd suggest using the titles 'Home' and 'Blog'.

Go to Settings -> Reading. Choose 'A static page'. Select 'Home' for front page and 'Blog' for posts page.

The templates you've created (front-page.php & home.php) will automatically be applied.

You'll then be able to select the posts page, 'Blog', in the menu editor.

Comment: Excellent, pleased to hear I was able to help.